# Unable to append forecast results into a vector or dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, forecast

I have a dataframe with each column representing data for a year (from 2000 to 2018). I am using simple `forecast()` function to predict the result for 2019.

The issue is while using for loop to generate forecast for 4000+ rows, I am unable to generate a vector or dataframe containing forecast for each row.

Here's the code I am using:

```
Data = data.frame(2000 = c(...),2001 = c(...),...,2018 = c(...))

dfe = c()

for (i in 1:nrow(Data)) {
    tseries = ts(unlist(Data[i,6:24], start = 2000, end = 2018, frequency = 1)
    fo = forecast(tseries, h = 1)
    valfo = append(dfe, as.vector(fo$mean))
}
```

I am expecting a single vector with predictions for 2019 for all 4000+ rows of Data. But when I run this code, R throws a single value.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide some example data. I'm not sure why you're using a for loop - most models in R will produce a forecast for every row in a data.frame.

Comment: I just want simple forecast using forecast() for 2020. The data is: Data = data.frame("2017" = c(20,30,45,66,12), "2018" = c(11,54,65,22,78), "2019" = c(9,76,33,53,77)). I am kind of new to using R. Can you please help as in how to project for 2020 for each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just seems to be an issue with how you're assigning the results. Your current code is overwriting the result at the end of each loop.

Try this:

```
Data = data.frame("2017" = c(20,30,45,66,12), "2018" = c(11,54,65,22,78), "2019" = c(9,76,33,53,77))

dfe = c()

for (i in 1:nrow(Data)) {
  tseries = ts(unlist(Data[i,1:3]), start = 2017, end = 2019, frequency = 1)
  fo = forecast(tseries, h = 1)
  dfe[[i]] <- as.vector(fo$mean)
  valfo <- unlist(dfe)
}
```

This should give you a vector `valfo` of your forecasts.

Comment: Happy to help. If it solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: What if I want to project for next 2 periods i.e. for 2020 and 2021?

Comment: You could just repeat the above for loop, changing the "end" parameter.
Or, if you're wanting to forecast for many years ahead, create an additional for loop, "outside" the above one, where the "end" variable is automatically changed by "j"